# Why bounties are not yet allowed

Tags: support, status-bydesign

Like many other SE sites, why can't I offer a bounty?

Is there any criteria for a SE site to start a bounty?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is based on a false premise.

Comment: @AlexanderRossa what's the false premise? It asks why they can't start a bounty, just asking for reasons. It doesn't say _anything_ about the 2 day limit.

Comment: @Riker The false premise is that there is some **bounty ban** imposed on the *whole site and every question in it*. There is not and there never was, if the question was old enough, bounty could be offered for answering it since the start of the private beta. This is not a question wondering why bounty cannot be offered on questions younger than 2 days, this is simply a question asking about something that does not exist - hence, the false premise.

Comment: @AlexanderRossa then edit it out. (I've done that).

Comment: @Riker I do not think it is my right to change someone else's question to what I see fit with disregard to what he meant it to be. If I think it is wrong I can point that out and vote to close it, not edit it to be something completely different than originally.

Comment: @AlexanderRossa it's not significantly different IMO, it's mostly just a misunderstanding (as you noted). Regardless, it's not off-topic in its current state.

Comment: @Riker Well, I believe it is. Just as the original question, it still introduces other SE sites to the picture, making the scope of it bigger than the Vegetarianism SE Meta - and if that is the case, where better to seek answers than the SE Meta? Hence, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work . This question does not relate to this SE site nor to its Meta in any way. It lacked in quality from the beginning and still does, just in a different, less obvious way. But I won't push the issue. I voted and I am stil convinced of the reasons for which I did so.

Answer (score 6):

You are probably looking at questions not yet 3 days old. Only questions older than 2 days are eligible for a bounty.

If you look at older questions, you'll see that you *can* start a bounty:

[image]

<sub>(Screenshot taken from [here](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/1))</sub>

Comment: I believe the period before bounties are allowed is 48 hours, according to the [help center](http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).